# RazorViewTest in .Net Core 2.2; the @Html.ValidationMessage("key") does not display anything

Tags: validation, .net-core, xunit, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I am writing a RazorViewTest using xUnit, and the code for my test is pretty straightforward:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task SimplePageWithModel()
        {
            var snapshot = await host
                .CreateRazorViewTest("/Pages/SimplePageWithModel.cshtml")
                .UseModel(new Pages.SimplePageWithModelModel { Message = "Hello from page model" })
                .UseModelSnapshot(m => new { m.Message })
                .BeforeRender((c, m) => {
                    m.ModelState.AddModelError("test", "Test Message");
                    m.ModelState.AddModelError("kir", "siktir");
                    })
                .Snapshot()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            AssertSnapshot.ToMatchYamlSnapshot(snapshot);
        }
```

Clearly, I am adding two model errors. The code for my Razor page is the following:

```
@page
@model SimplePageWithModelModel

<div>@Model.Message</div>

<h2>Model State Erros</h2>

<ol>
    @foreach (var modelEntry in ModelState)
    {
        <li>Html.ValidationMessage: <pre>@Html.ValidationMessage(modelEntry.Key)</pre></li>
        foreach (var error in modelEntry.Value.Errors)
        {
            <li>@(modelEntry.Key): @error.ErrorMessage</li>
        }
    }
</ol>
```

The part that is troubling me is that the inner loop is showing my model errors perfectly, but the `@Html.ValidationMessage(modelEntry.Key)` line always renders empty. What it renders is basically this:
`<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="kir" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`, no content in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just in case, if you see the errors if you add  <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div> to your view markup?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov No that doesn't add the errors to the page. However I know the errors are there since the inner loop does show them on the page!

Answer (score 0):

If you view `Model` has property `kir` try adding this as described in [validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation):

```
<span asp-validation-for="kir" class="text-danger"></span>
```